# Entity Framework: Query is slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, optimization

I am having some problems with Entity Framework.
I have simplified this to make it easier to explain.

These are my mssql tables
[image: mssql tables]

I use the following code to get all cities for each of the countries in my MSSQL database

```
var country = new Country()
{
    Cities = obj.Counties.SelectMany(e => e.Cities).Select(city => new DCCity
    {
        Name = city.Name,
        Population = city.Population
    })
};
```

This is returned as json

[image]

There is a bit more then 40.000 records in the city table. To retrieve a list with all the countries and their respective cities it takes around 8 seconds. I am trying to reduce this. Anyone know some optimization tips to achieve this?

Comment: Please post your full code. The snippet you've provided wouldn't produce that output.

Comment: Use the SQL Server Profiler to see what SQL is being sent to your database server.

Comment: Do you really need all 40k records?

Comment: I supose you make separate query for each county of each country

Comment: Do you run one query for each country rather than running one query to get all the data? Where does the JSON come into this, do you send the result as JSON somewhere, and is it possibly that which is taking a long time rather than the database query? How do you create the JSON, could that be the bottle neck?

Comment: Sounds like a Web API call. Is it 8 seconds just for the query to run, or for the entire call? Keep in mind, those 40,000 records needs to be packaged up in the required format (iterated through to form that JSON) and then transferred across the wire to whoever is waiting to get the response. That will take some time.

Comment: Have you ever looked at perhaps maintaining a view that has the information you need and just reading that instead of joining the three tables?

Comment: Do you have an index on the countyId column of the City table? That  may help you query speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the Cities table first to get all data:

```
var cities = _context.Cities.Select(x => new {
    ContryId = x.County.Country.CountryId,
    ContryName = x.County.Country.Name,
    CityId = x.Id,
    CityName = x.Name
});

var countryLookup = new Dictionary<int, CountryDto>(approximatelyCountOfCountries);

foreach (var city in cities)
{
    CountryDto country;
    if (!countryLookup.TryGetValue(city.CountryId, out country))
    {
        country = new CountryDto {
            Name = city.CountryName,
            Id = city.CountryId
            Cities = new List<CityDto>(approximatelyCountOfCities)
        };
        countryLookup.Add(country.Id, country);
    }
    country.Cities.Add(new CityDto { Name = city.Name, Id = city.Id });
}
```

In this way the result will be the:

```
countryLookup.Values
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do somthing like this:

```
            var result = from c in countries
                     join conty in counties on c.id equals conty.CountryId
                     join city in cities on conty.id equals city.CountyId

                     group city by c.Name into g

                     select new
                     {
                         Name = g.Key,
                         Cities = g.Select(x =>
                             new
                             {
                                 x.Name,
                                 x.Population
                             })
                     };
```